# How to POST Json metadata through API using placeholders

Tags: javascript, json, post, metadata

how are you doing? Thank you for your help in advance!

There is a platform for NFT minting (https://pro.nft-maker.io/) that allows me to set up a metadata structure for the files I'm gonna upload later using their API. Mine looks like this:

```
{
    "721": {
        "<policy_id>": {
            "<asset_name>": {
                "one": "<place_holder1>",
                "two": "<place_holder2>",
                "three": "<place_holder3>",
                "four": "<place_holder4>",
                "five": "<place_holder5>",
                "six": "<place_holder6>",
                "seven": "<place_holder7>",
                "eight": "<place_holder8>",
                "nine": "<place_holder9>",
                "files": [
                    {
                        "name": "<asset_name>",
                        "mediaType": "<mime_type>",
                        "src": "<ipfs_link>"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Those in `<brackets>` are my placeholders. I need to pass data to them using a POST Request in JSON when I'm uploading the images.

This is their API Documentation:
https://api.nft-maker.io/swagger/index.html

I'll need to use the UploadNft endpoint to POST and Upload my image and its metadata. This is the sample code from the Documentation:

```
{
  "assetName": "string",
  "previewImageNft": {
    "mimetype": "string",
    "fileFromIPFS": "string",
    "metadataPlaceholder": [
      {
        "name": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  "metadata": "string"
}
```

The structure is from Cardano Blockchain CIP25: https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/

According to the API Documentation, I could either use the `metadata:""` to completely override the Project Metadata I've setup in the project creation (first code of the question), or I could use the `metadataPlaceholder: [{}]` to assign values to the placeholders I've created in the Project Metadata.

On my mind, I would only need to do this to Upload a new image and metadata:

```
{
    "assetName": "Testing1",
    "previewImageNft": {
        "mimetype": "image/png",
        "fileFromIPFS": "QmUp9ZnFbHegzdwtg8ToXJK7kjrJrkZcKuCuXGAREeXNDr",
        "metadataPlaceholder": [
            {
                "place_holder1": "The info I need goes here",
                "place_holder2": "The info I need goes here",
                "place_holder3": "The info I need goes here",
                "place_holder4": "The info I need goes here"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The thing is, when I post the code above (that can be done using their API Documentation "Try it out" system), I'm able to see the new image uploaded on the dashboard, but the Metadata didn't change at all:

[image: result]

The placeholder that should receive the data I've POST returns as a blank string `""`.

This is what my POST look like:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
 'https://api.nft-maker.io/UploadNft/****/****' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "assetName": "Testing01",
    "previewImageNft": {
        "mimetype": "image/png",
        "fileFromIPFS": "QmUp9ZnFbHegzdwtg8ToXJK7kjrJrkZcKuCuXGAREeXNDr",
        "metadataPlaceholder": [
            {
                "place_holder1": "The info I need goes here",
                "place_holder2": "The info I need goes here",
                "place_holder3": "The info I need goes here",
                "place_holder4": "The info I need goes here"
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

This is the Response Body I get after the POST:

```
{
  "nftId": 614865,
  "ipfsHashMainnft": "QmUp9ZnFbHegzdwtg8ToXJK7kjrJrkZcKuCuXGAREeXNDr",
  "ipfsHashSubfiles": [],
  "metadata": "{\r\n  \"721\": {\r\n    \"<policy_id>"\": {\r\n      \"Testing01\": {\r\n        \"one\": \"\",\r\n        \"two\": \"\",\r\n        \"three\": \"\",\r\n        \"four\": \"\",\r\n        \"five\": \"\",\r\n        \"six\": \"\",\r\n        \"seven\": \"\",\r\n        \"eight\": \"\",\r\n        \"nine\": \"\",\r\n        \"files\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"name\": \"Testing01\",\r\n            \"mediaType\": \"image/png\",\r\n            \"src\": \"ipfs://QmUp9ZnFbHegzdwtg8ToXJK7kjrJrkZcKuCuXGAREeXNDr\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
}
```

I have the option of manually overriding the entire image metadata using their dashboard:

[image: Manual metadata override]

or, I can also manually replace my placeholders:

[image: Manual metadata placeholders]

After replacing the data manually, I can see the correct metadata on the dashboard:

[image: Correct metadata after manually replacing it]

And if I use their GetNftDetails API endpoint for that image, I get this:

```
{
  "id": 614865,
  "ipfshash": "QmUp9ZnFbHegzdwtg8ToXJK7kjrJrkZcKuCuXGAREeXNDr",
  "state": "free",
  "name": "Testing01",
  "minted": false,
  "receiveraddress": null,
  "selldate": null,
  "soldby": null,
  "reserveduntil": null,
  "policyid": null,
  "assetid": null,
  "assetname": null,
  "fingerprint": null,
  "initialminttxhash": null,
  "title": null,
  "series": null,
  "ipfsGatewayAddress": "https://gw2.easy-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmUp9ZnFbHegzdwtg8ToXJK7kjrJrkZcKuCuXGAREeXNDr",
  "metadata": "{\r\n  \"721\": {\r\n    \"<policy_id>\": {\r\n      \"Testing01\": {\r\n        \"one\": \"Manually Editing the FIRST\",\r\n        \"two\": \"Manually Editing the SECOND\",\r\n        \"three\": \"Manually Editing the THIRD\",\r\n        \"files\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"name\": \"Testing01\",\r\n            \"mediaType\": \"image/png\",\r\n            \"src\": \"ipfs://QmUp9ZnFbHegzdwtg8ToXJK7kjrJrkZcKuCuXGAREeXNDr\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
}
```

I've also tried to POST using the `"metadata": ""` instead of the `"metadataPlaceholder":[{}]`, like so:

```
{
    "assetName": "Testing01",
    "previewImageNft": {
        "mimetype": "image/png",
        "fileFromIPFS": "QmUp9ZnFbHegzdwtg8ToXJK7kjrJrkZcKuCuXGAREeXNDr"
    },
    "metadata": "{\r\n  \"721\": {\r\n    \"<policy_id>\": {\r\n      \"Testing01\": {\r\n        \"one\": \"FIRST\",\r\n        \"two\": \"SECOND\",\r\n        \"three\": \"THIRD\",\r\n        \"files\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"name\": \"Testing01\",\r\n            \"mediaType\": \"image/png\",\r\n            \"src\": \"ipfs://QmUp9ZnFbHegzdwtg8ToXJK7kjrJrkZcKuCuXGAREeXNDr\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
}
```

It POSTs just fine, I can see the image there, BUT I have the same problem, blank `""` metadata where I have the placeholders.

There is some NFT projects currently using this platform, and they don't seem to have a problem generating this metadata...

With all of that being said... Am I being that stupid? What am I doing wrong that I can't see?

Do you guys have any idea how I should structure this metadata in the API UploadNft endpoint so I can POST it with no problem?

*I've send a e-mail for them, but couldn't get a answer yet.

Comment: Could you provide some of your server-side code as far as how you process the POST? In my NodeJS server I was able to retrieve all the placeholders using body-parser (`require('body-parser')`) and then `console.log(request.body['key']['<main>']['<sub>'])`

Comment: @Joey, I've edited the post with more information, hope it can be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to post the placeholder as an array with the fields "name" and "value".

So it should looks like this:

```json
"metadataPlaceholder": [
  {
    "name": "color",
    "value": "red"
  },
  {
    "name": "size",
    "value": "big"
  },
  {
    "name": "placerholder3",
    "value": "value3"
  }
]
```

Comment: You're the man, Sascha! Thank you, thank you, thank you. I knew it was some stupid mistake on my part, hahaha